# Prevent Sticky UICollectionView Section Header Getting Pushed Up by Section Footer

Tags: ios, uicollectionview, swift3, uicollectionviewcell, uicollectionreusableview

This is how I stick the sectionHeader to the top of collectionView when it scrolls

```
    (collectionView.collectionViewLayout as? UICollectionViewFlowLayout)?.sectionHeadersPinToVisibleBounds = true;
```

The problem is that, when the header hit a footer, it gets pushed up by the footer.

How do we make sure that a header can only be pushed up by another header?

Thank you

Comment: So, what did you expect? Should the footer scroll up **behind** the header?

Comment: Yes? @ReinhardMänner

Comment: @Jay - (collectionView.collectionViewLayout as? UICollectionViewFlowLayout)?.sectionFootersPinToVisibleBounds = false;  have you tried this?

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you try creating one cell for the footer which will be a subclass of UICollectionViewCell and add it at the end of every section by adding 1 for number of rows for every section. then you will have a header which will not be pushed up by your footer